# Element.style.left property refuses to take value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got an issue with the element position properties, in particular the 'left' property. I've created a grey block shape in css and rotated it by 0.17rad in js. I want to move the block diagonally across the screen so that it moves a distance of 3px for every 20 milliseconds. If you use your good old SOHCAHTOA and pythagoras laws, that comes out to **0.5075470472px** in the left direction and **2.956754301px** in the upwards direction every 20ms.

html:

```
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='block'></div>
    <script src='.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
#block {
   width: 19px;
   height: 31px;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: grey;
}
```

js:

```
var block = document.getElementById('block');

block.style.left = '0px';
block.style.top = '500px';
block.style.transform = 'rotate(0.17rad)';

setInterval(function() {
   block.style.left = (parseInt(block.style.left) + 0.5075470472) + 'px';
   block.style.top = (parseInt(block.style.top) - 2.956754301) + 'px';
}, 20);
```

What happens in my case is the block moves correctly in the upward direction but doesn't move at all in the left direction. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you have a div in the `<head>` ?

Comment: Idk, is it wrong? Soz ima noob :P

Comment: Yes.  Elements that display on the page go in the `<body>`, not the `<head>`  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-head-element

Comment: Ok, fixed it, still doesn't work :/

Comment: Thx tho might save me one day :)

Comment: If this is your actual code, you're missing the reference to your script. You have literally just `.js` inside your `src` attribute.

Comment: Your code works just fine. @MarcusParsons have the right issue in place. See JSBin or JSFiddle for testing your code before posting the question. https://jsbin.com/bocudahori/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @Marcus Parsons - Nope, not a problem, the js file i created doesn't have a name, I do it all the time.

Comment: @Idan - Just tried it in JSFiddle, doesn't work at all, block only moves in the upwards direction but not to the left :/

Comment: Use `parseFloat` instead and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseInt` is rounding the numbers, what you need is to use `parseFloat`:

```
block.style.left = (parseFloat(block.style.left) + 0.5075470472) + 'px';
block.style.top = (parseFloat(block.style.top) - 2.956754301) + 'px';
```